# Do single use plants count as losing a plant?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

One of the conditions for a star on a level is to lose no more than 1 plant.  Do single use plants like the iceberg lettuce count as losing a plant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I should have just tried to pick one for the level.  If you try to take a single use plant on a mission with that restriction, a big warning pops up telling you that it does count as losing a plant.